# Revealing pattern not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

```
(function( Pbr) {

    Pbr.ShowHomePage = function() {
        console.log("ShowHomePage called")
    }

    function privateFunc() {
        console.log("Showtitle");
    }

    return {
        ShowTitle : privateFunc
    }

}(Pbr = Pbr || {}));


Pbr.ShowHomePage()
Pbr.ShowTitle()
```

I am trying implement Revealing pattern. But it fails to work.
ShowHomePage is working fine, but ShowTitle is not working

Comment: You never do anything with the return value of the function, hence the object you return is just lost. You might want to assign `ShowTitle` to `Pbr` as well.

Comment: `this` is important ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to reveal your methods by attaching them to the argument, not by returning them. Use

```
(function(Pbr) {

    Pbr.ShowHomePage = function() {
        console.log("ShowHomePage called")
    }

    function privateFunc() {
        console.log("Showtitle");
    }
    Pbr.ShowTitle = privateFunc; // not very private, btw

}(Pbr = Pbr || {}));
```

If you want to `return` an object literal, you will need to assign the result of the IEFE, and overwrite existing `Pbr` values. It would look like

```
var Pbr = (function() {

    function privateFunc() {
        console.log("Showtitle");
    }

    return {
        ShowTitle: privateFunc
        ShowHomePage: function() {
            console.log("ShowHomePage called")
        }
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

As Felix said in comments, you need to use the return value.

Either assign the full module to `Pbr` and reveal `ShowHomePage` as well (as you have done for privatefunc).

Or, add `Pbr.ShowTitle = privatefunc;` in your module and remove the return statement.